# Camera solve, align the 3D space with the footage

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm adding the 3D object into the footage I shoot, after camera solving I got error 0.28px which is pretty good, then I want to check if the angle is correctly aligned with my footage so I put a long vertical cube and check if the edge of the cube is in parallel with the edge I have in the video clip, then I got bellow result,

[image: Edge not aligned]

Then I rotate the camera to solve the issue which I got this

[image: Aligned]

My question is,

Do you in your workflow needs to align the camera solve with the footage like what I did? By putting a long vertical thing to check if it matches the footage? Why my camera solve error is pretty decent but still it has such huge misalignment? And do you also needs to algin the grid to the edge of the wall?